# Spark Streaming Re-Use Physical Plan

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

We have a Spark Streaming application, which performs a few heavy stateful computation against the incoming stream of data. Here the state is maintained in some storage (HDFS/Hive/Hbase/Cassandra) and at the end of every window the delta change in state is updated back using Append Only write strategy.

The issue is that for each and every window the **`planning phase`** is taking a lot of time; in-fact more than the compute time.

```scala
    dStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
        val dataset_1 = rdd.toDS()
        val dataset_2 = dataset_1.join(..)
        val dataset_3 = dataset_2
         .map(..)
         .filter(..)
         .join(..)

        // A few more Joins & Transformations

        val finalDataset = ..

        finalDataset
         .write
         .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 5000)
         .format(save_format)
         .mode("append")
         .insertInto("table_name")

    })
```

Is there a way to re-use the **Physical Plan** from the last window and avoid planning stages every window by Spark, because practically nothing would have changed between windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so and that's one of the many reasons why you should be using [Spark Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) instead.

Among the features of the underlying stream engine is to re-use physical plan of a streaming query.

Comment: Thanks @JacekLaskowski !! Does that also mean that the Physical Plan of Joined Dataset's will also be analyzed only once across multiple windows in Structured Streaming. Here those Joined Dataset's won't be cached and are expected to execute on every window.

Comment: That's my understanding. The only change between batches is whether there's a new input from any of the sources or not. Windowing is part of a physical plan that's responsible for loading the respective state and it's internal to the physical operator.